# XSLT: string-length($variable) gives a wrong answer

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xsl variable that looks like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="all" >
    abab
</xsl:variable>
```

Now I want to compute the length of the above variable (`all`) so I try to do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-length($all)"/>
```

I expect 4 to be my answer (4 characters in the string 'abab') but I get 39.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well use `<xsl:variable name="all" select="'abab'"/>` or `<xsl:variable name="all">abab</xsl:variable>`, if you insert white space before and after the letters then of course they are part of the text node's content and part of the string whose length you compute.

Comment: Ah! got it. Silly me!

Answer (score 3):

Either define the variable without the whitespace characters, or use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-length(normalize-space($all))"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for normalise function